# Conversão de array de inteiros em String

Tags: java, array, string, int, inteiros

Sou  iniciante em Java e gostaria de aprender como converto um array de inteiros em uma String.

Comment: Converter como? Tipo, se seu array tiver os elementos `10`, `20` e `30` a string resultante deve ser `"102030"`? Por favor esclareça melhor seu problema, mostre onde quer chegar e o que já conseguiu fazer até agora (i.e. diga o que sabe, pra gente te ajudar no que não sabe).

Answer (score 6):

Para converteres uma matriz do tipo `int` para uma `string` deverás fazer uso do método **[`.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29)** que faz parte da *class* `java.util.Arrays`:

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

Que traduzido:

> Retorna uma representação string do conteúdo da matriz especificada.

## Exemplo:

[Demostração no ideone.com](http://ideone.com/iSng2W)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final int[] matriz = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matriz));
    }
}
```

## Resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```